# Joomla. How to get a model if I have got it before

Tags: php, joomla, static, joomla-extensions

For example, if I get some model in a controller, then the model save some its properties. But if I get the same model in a view or somethig else again, the changes disappear.

```
$model1 = $this ->getModel();
$model1 ->value = 123;

$model2 = $this ->getModel();
echo $model2 ->value; //Empty
```

I tried to use $model2 =& $this ->getModel(); but it is useless;

Is it possible to get the same model with its changed properties in every place?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is a little confusing. Are you saying you want to instantiate a model in a view? Or are you asking how does Joomla get the data from the model to the view?  If you are in a controller or view `$this` is going to be a controller or view class, not a model object so it is not going to have a getModel() method.

Comment: For example, I have a model "Settings". It fetches data from database. But I need to get  the data in various parts of my extension. I think it is not a good idea to ask the model to ask the database every time. I supposed that there is a mechanism should be to store (cache) the fetched data. Now I use setUserState() to store the data , but I think this method is not for such cases.

Comment: Have you looked at how the Joomla MVC works? Yes setUserState is not a bad idea for some kinds of data (like filters) and caching is not a bad idea either. Many joomla components use the internal cache, which is why you see the setStoreId() methods all over the place. I suggest that you look closely at the structure of the core components>

Comment: Yes, now I am on position "Developing a MVC Component/Adding backend actions". Which core component should be the first for learning?

Comment: People always suggest weblinks, in some ways it is the simplest.

Comment: Since you mention Settings as a model name, maybe a helper would be easier to work with, it will be static so you'll always get the same instance